# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, exc-bad-access, didselectrowatindexpath

this is my first post here, after getting tones of help by reading all the great answers I've finally run into a problem I can't solve. I'm new so please excuse my lack or prowess in my code.

I've got a split view controller running a tab bar with two Table view controllers in it. That all works fine. Each cell is a menu item that I want to load a new navigation controller in the detail view of the splitViewController.

I've done this by adding the following code to the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method that is located in my uiTableViews class. I've also created a calls with a method to simplify the process which I've called SplitViewChange.

It works fine on my first cell selection and sometimes for more than one but more often than not it bombs on the second cell selection with the error EXC_BAD_ACCESS

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    AdminData *_adminData = self.adminNav[indexPath.row];
NSString *newVcController = _adminData.vcName;

//get a referce to the splitviewcontroller
//UISplitViewController *splitViewController = self.splitViewController;
UISplitViewController  *splitViewController = self.splitViewController;
//ref the cuttent navigation controller in the rootvuew
UINavigationController *currentNavigation = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
//run the method to put the viewcontrollers into a single array
NSArray *viewControllers = [SplitViewChange setVcName:newVcController setCurrentNavigation:currentNavigation];

splitViewController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
}
```

Then here is the code for my class and it's method -

```
@implementation SplitViewChange

+(NSArray *)setVcName:(NSString *)vcName setCurrentNavigation:(UINavigationController *)currentNavigation
{
 //get a ref to the main storyboard to referece the navigation controllers
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];

//get a ref to the new detail view controller
UINavigationController *newDetailView = (UINavigationController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:vcName];

NSArray *controllerArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:currentNavigation, newDetailView, nil];

return controllerArray;
}

@end
```

Any help making this work would be most welcomed.

I get the error on this line

```
splitViewController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
```

Comment: at which line are you receiving your EXC_BAD_ACCESS error?

Comment: Make NSZombieEnabled ON. And check why are you getting this crash

Comment: It's at the splitViewController.viewControllers = viewControllers; line, it gets highlighted in green.

Comment: I have actually same problem, and I have no idea why.